# How can I fix the editing functionality in my React ToDo app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Todos = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [input, setInput] = useState([]);
    const [addBtn, saveBtn] = useState(true);

    const addTodobtn = () => {
        // setTodos((oldlist) => [...oldlist, input]);

        let inputHere = document.querySelector("#inputHere");
        let errmsg = document.querySelector("#errmsg");
        if (inputHere.value !== "") {
            errmsg.style.display = "none"
            setTodos((listData) => {
                const updateTodo = [...listData, input];
                // console.log(updateTodo);
                setInput("");
                return updateTodo;
            })
        }
        else {
            errmsg.style.display = "block";
            inputHere.focus();
            return errmsg.innerHTML = "Feed the data inside input box";
        }
    }
    const deletetodo = (i) => {
        const updateTodohere = todos.filter((elm, ind) => {
            return i !== ind;
        })
        setTodos(updateTodohere);
    }

    const edittodo = (indd) => {
        let findItem = todos.find((elm, ind) => {
            return indd === ind;
        });
        saveBtn(false);
        setInput(findItem);
    }
    const saveTodobtn = () => {
        saveBtn(true);
    }
    const deleteAll = () => {
        setTodos([]);
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Todos here below:-</h1>
            <p id="errmsg"></p>
            <input type="text" value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter ToDo" id="inputHere" />

            {
                addBtn ? <button type='button' onClick={addTodobtn}>Add Todo</button> : <button type='button' onClick={() => saveTodobtn()}>Save Todo</button>
            }
            <div className='resultbelow'>
                <h4>Your Todo list here-</h4>
                {todos != [] && todos.map((data, ind) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className='d-flex mb25' key={ind}>
                                <div>
                                    <p className='anshere'>{data}</p>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <button onClick={() => edittodo(ind)} >Edit</button>
                                    <button onClick={() => deletetodo(ind)}>X</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })}
                {todos.length >= 1 && <button onClick={deleteAll}>Remove All</button>}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default Todos;
```

I want a Todo application based on React, I tried and I am including my coding structure above. Here, through useState effect I am holding every required datas inside here. Also, successfully every other functionality like- adding, deleting, removing all functionality is working except this- editing functionality.

I am unable to figure it out. Also, can anyone please help me out and is my coding process is good or not.Kindly suggest here too?